# pig: filtering out empty string

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to filter out NULL and empty string from my data

```
data_filtered = FILTER raw_data by COLUMN_NAME is not null and COLUMN_NAME != '' ;
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <file jhoughton/temp/temp_script.pig, line 43, column 46>  Unexpected character ' '
```

How can I resolve this error and filter out both NULLS and blank strings?

Comment: A single space is suffice between raw_data and BY clause. For checking a string for not empty you can just check it for NOT NULL - It will take filter out : '', ' ' and NULL characters.

Answer (score 2):

you can use TRIM function to filter empty spaces

```
data_filtered = FILTER raw_data by ( COLUMN_NAME is not null and TRIM(COLUMN_NAME) != '' );
```

Answer (score 1):

(In-)Equality for Strings is not established through !=  or == in Pig.

The correct syntax is:

```
data_filtered = FILTER raw_data BY (COLUMN_NAME is not null) AND  NOT(COLUMN_NAME MATCHES "");
```